# Question About SubSonic Version 2.2

Tags: subsonic

(Warning: This may be a stupid question...)

I am am one of those who are not willing to move to SubSonic 3.0.  I am currently using a customized fork of SubSonic 1.(?).  I want to migrate to version 2 for many reasons, and I have been successfully been playing with Subcommander.  Cool stuff!  Here's my question...

When I generate the DAL for 2 databases, when I put those DAL files into the same project, with SubSonic 2.2 allow me to connect to both of them in the same project/application at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, but they will need to be in separate namespaces (I think).  I've done it and I found that giving each its own project and namespace was the easiest to manage - especially with subcommander since each project can have its own config file.

You may also want to take a look at the SubStage application.  I found it great for discovering the myriad of settings available with SubSonic code generation.

Comment: I wouldn't worry, subsonic 2.2 is much better than v1. And I wouldn't try to have both, I would just port to v2.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple database support was first introduced with SubSonic 2.0 Beta 1. It is hard to find samples online, but the Starter Site project is still a good reference as it includes two database references. You can find [the source](http://code.google.com/p/subsoniccms/) on Google Code.